# In cat, vim, nano and other similar situations, the mouse wheel cannot be used

Tags: linux, windows, wsl-2

#### Windows Version

`Windows11 pro 22H2`

#### WSL Version

```
Kernel Version： 5.15.133.1-1
WSLg Version： 1.0.59
MSRDC Version： 1.2.4677
Direct3D Version： 1.611.1-81528511
DXCore Version： 10.0.25880.1000-230602-1350.main
Windows Version： 10.0.22621.2428
```

#### system

`Ubuntu 23.04`

#### Repro Steps

use `vim` `nano` `cat` Similar file viewing/editing programs. open any file.

#### for example

`sudo nano /etc/systemd/system.conf`

Unable to scroll up and down with mouse wheel Can only be scrolled via keyboard ↑↓

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: Sounds like it should go into a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues) and not Stack Overflow, or at the very least into a post at [su].

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you cannot scroll in nano, though it may have limited access to the mouse in cases, please try using the command "--mouse".please check if it works.